# Coordinate change expansion

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, coordinate-systems, perturbation-theory

Suppose there is a function $f(\vec{x})$ which can be given as a perturbative expansion of the form
$$f(x) = f_0 (x) + f_1 (x) + f_2 (x)+\cdots$$ 
where $f_n$ represents a function of order some $\epsilon^n$, where $\epsilon\ll 1$.

Now suppose I introduce a new variable $y$ such that
$$x= g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots$$
where $g_n$ represents a monomial of $y$ with coefficient of order $\epsilon^n$ .

I want to obtain the perturbative expansion of $f(y)$, such that
$$f(y)= \hat{f}_0 (y) + \hat{f}_1 (y) + \hat{f}_2 (y)+\cdots.$$

I presume one does this by expanding 
$$f(y)= f_0 \left( g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots\right) + f_1 \left( g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots\right) +\cdots\\\\
$$

where by $f_0\left( g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots\right)$ I mean using the exact expression of $f_0(x)$ but substitute in $x=\left( g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots\right)$..
Is this right?

**[UPDATE:]**
What should one do when the relation between the coordinates is given in terms of 
$$y= h_0(x) + h_1(x)+\cdots$$ instead?

Comment: $x=\left( g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots\right)$ implies
$f_0(x) = f_0\left( g_0(y) + g_1(y)+\cdots\right)$, so if this is all the question - you are fine.

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelMedvinsky, Sorry, what I meant to ask is in the update section.

Comment: you need $f(x)$, but you have $y=g(x)$, so you need $f(g^{-1}(y))$ if that $g^{-1}$ exists at all..., am I getting you correctly?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky, I don't have g(x) in full, only up to a finite order...

Comment: if you don't have even $g(x)$ then we talking about approximations, correct?